# Saving Excel File as Table in the Django Database

Tags: django, excel, django-templates

is there any way to save an Excel File to the Django Database, so i can call the sheet with e.g. Document.objects.all?

I have this as my `views.py`.

```
    def read_file(request):
        file = 'C:/Users/admin/Desktop/djangoexcel/media/documents /TestExcel.xlsx'
        test = pd.read_excel(file)
        test2 = (pd.DataFrame.to_html(test, classes = 'table table-striped'))
        return TemplateResponse(request, 'documents/read_file.html', {'test2' : test2})

    def index(request):
        documents = Document
        template = loader.get_template('documents/index.html')
        context = {
        'documents': documents
        }
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

    def model_form_upload(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('documents:index')
        else:
            form = DocumentForm()
        return render(request, 'documents/model_form_upload.html', {
            'form': form
        })
```

This is my `models.py`

```
class Document(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to="documents/")
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I would like to manipulate the data from the Excel Sheet through a template so i can update, delete and add entries on the website with generic views or something like that. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Do you want to store the contents of the excel file or the file itself (your model does the latter while you seem to ask for the former)?

Comment: Exactly. I would like to save the contents of the file in the database so i can manipulate the data through the admin site or through a template by looping over the content of the file. That is the problem i have. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Check out [django-import-export](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export).